# Convert string to an array in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How can ı convert a string to an array in shell script?

For example i want to put "apple" to an array.

```
array[0] = a
array[1]=p
array[2]=p
array[3]=l
array[4]=e
```

I tried a lot of things but none of them worked. I tried to use IFS but i have no space or comma in my word so it didn't work.

Comment: Umm. Is your expected result `array[0]="apple"`?, or is your expected result `array=( [0]=a [1]=p [2]=p [3]=l [4]=e )`? Don't just show what you're doing, show how you're testing whether it worked, and show the output you _want_ that test to have.

Comment: (Or if you're _only_ showing the output you want, also describe how you're trying to accomplish it! We generally don't do "write your program for you" here; we answer questions, ideally ones about narrow, specific problems that can be demonstrated via code you already wrote, which means we expect you to _show your existing code_)

Comment: Bro chill out. This is the first time I have asked something on StackOverflow. So you don't have to be so offensive. I just started to learn shell script plus I don't need you to write my code. I don't know the language so well, so I asked about it.

Comment: What's offensive? Since you're new here, there's a lot of guidance on how best to navigate the site to be learned-- it's a lot shorter (and more helpful) for advice on how to comply with the site's rules to be compressed in a few short sentences, like the above, than to ask you to read the whole [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) front-to-back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) is relevant here: `${#var}` gives you the number of characters in `var`, and `${var:start:len}` takes `len` characters from `var`, starting at position `start`.

Combine those two techniques and you get:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
string='apple'
array=( )
for ((i=0; i<${#string}; i++)); do
  array[$i]=${string:i:1}
done
declare -p array
```

...which emits as output:

```
declare -a array=([0]="a" [1]="p" [2]="p" [3]="l" [4]="e")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. I didn't even know a page existed like Bash Hackers Wiki . I appreciate that.